# Jest Angular testing gives karma error `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'karma'`

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to use jest testing in Angular. I have done all the configuration described here  [enter link description here](https://blog.skarby.info/jest-with-angular/)

Here is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "jest-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:ci": "jest -ci --runInBand",
    
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^8.3.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|html)$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

here is tsconfig.spec.ts

```
  /* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest",
      "jsdom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have also added the setupjest.ts. I only have import 'jest-preset-angular';

now when I run ng test it gives karma not found error.

Comment: Hi, did you add the [TestPathIgnorePattern](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular#avoid-karma-conflicts) option?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use the briebug jest schematic to add jest to your project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@briebug/jest-schematic) as it's maintained rather than using a 2 years old blog post.